# Webservice throws ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

AddService is a webservice that was created using ApacheTomcat,Eclipse and Axis2

```
import auctiondao.UsersDAO;

public class AddService {
    public String checkUser(String username,String password) {
        UsersDAO usersDAO=new UsersDAO();
        String user=usersDAO.checkUserExists(username, password);
        System.out.println("User....."+user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I have already added the project auction to the buildpath of webservice project.But when I try to run it.
I get the following ClassPath exception

```
[ERROR] auctiondao/UsersDAO
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
atorg.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageRecei    ver.java:117)
atorg.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractI    nOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at  org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: auctiondao/UsersDAO
at AddService.checkUser(AddService.java:5)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: auctiondao.UsersDAO
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
... 26 more
```

I am new to webservices.Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is the UserDao class on your project? On your code it is imported. Maybe it is in a different project that you didn't build therefore it is not on the server classpath.

Comment: It is in a different project.I have added it to the buildpath.

Comment: You added it to the buildpath of YOUR project (probably on your IDE). When you run it, it should have a generated jar to be added on the server you are running the service. What is the server you are running? Embbeded to the IDE or a external server?

Comment: The tomcat is part of IDE.Okie will try doing as you suggested.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your web project's properties, go to Deployment Assembly tab and use the 'Add' button to add the DAO project/module to the web project's classpath, as shown in the image here -

[image: Web Deployment Assembly]

Comment: Hey Thanks.Will try it and let you know